# Prevent access to certain posts, pages, attachments and category terms with map_meta_cap

Tags: php, wordpress, authorization

I'm trying to prevent some users from accessing certain posts, pages, categories and attachments both in the admin interface ("backend") and on the actual site ("frontend").

I've solved the frontend using a `template_redirect` action, checking if the `wp_get_current_user()` is allowed to view the `global $post` and if not just trigger a 404.

I've also solved most lists of posts using a `pre_get_posts` filter. Even lists inside the admin (though not all lists unfortunately).

However, inside the admin a user can still potentially edit any post, attachment, category or page he actually shouldn't have access to simply by entering the right URL like `/wp-admin/post.php?post=SOME_ID&action=edit`.

I've tried to fix this using the `map_meta_cap` filter, and while it seems to work for posts and pages (and attachments when viewing the normal edit screen), I can't get it to work for attachment "popups" (when you click an attachment in the list and get a popup with this type of URL: `/wp-admin/upload.php?item=SOME_ID`) or categories (`/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=SOME_ID&post_type=post`).

First of all I'm not even sure which capability I should be filtering for attachments and categories, but I've been trying with `upload_files` and `manage_categories` but there's no way of knowing which post/term is being edited:

```
add_filter('map_meta_cap', function ($caps, $cap, $user_id, $args) {
    # NOTE: $args[0] contains the post->ID
    if (in_array($cap, ['edit_post', 'delete_post', 'edit_page', 'delete_page']) and !can_current_user_access_post($args[0])) {
        return ['do_not_allow'];
    }
    elseif (in_array($cap, ['upload_files'])) {
        # NOTE: $args is false, not sure how to check if user can access current attachment
    }
    elseif (in_array($cap, ['manage_categories'])) {
        # NOTE: $args is false, not sure how to check if user can access current term
    }

    return $caps;
}, 10, 4);
```

I'm also curious why I can't simply add `read_post` and `read_page` to the caps I'm checking to prevent read access? (Which would allow me to delete my `template_redirect` code).

Also, if I could get this `map_meta_cap` code to work well everywhere (even for `read`) I could probably remove my `pre_get_posts` filter which would be nice.

I've never used `map_meta_cap` before and frankly I am a little lost as to how exactly it works.

Edit: I solved the category edit screen now too using the `edit_term` capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so turns out that `read_post` and `read_page` don't actually prevent anyone from reading posts or pages. Not sure what that does at all tbh. So my `template_redirect` is still needed to prevent access on the frontend.

Secondly, hiding attachments using the `pre_get_posts` filter actually takes care of the attachments popup issue too, because if the attachment isn't printed in the list of attachments the popup doesn't work (JS errors are thrown in the console when you try to access the popup) - I'm guessing because the popup code is printed in the same list.

Even though this is probably a bug, and probably not entirely secure, it works for my use case. I would prefer a `map_meta_cap` solution for the attachments popup too however.